# Jenkins Build Is Hanging

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, jenkins, robotframework

We are using Jenkins for continuous integration. I have already created a Jenkins job for running all my robot framework automation test scripts & Everything was absolutely working fine.

But now, it started showing a kind of issue .. Jenkins stopped running the robot framework test cases. It will start a particular job to execute automation test scripts, but it will stop working after running a few test cases. In the web console, it's just showing the loading spinner icon for a long time without throwing any error messages!

> [ All these test cases are working fine when I run through the command
>   line !    Using Selenium2Library for writing test cases ]

Here is the screenshot of the web console & Jenkins log file ( /var/log/jenkins.log)

[image]
[image]

Have you ever faced this kind of issue? Do you have any clue on this?

> I just went through the jenkins -> Manage jenkins -> manage nodes
>   sections & did not find any disk space issues here :

[image]

Comment: jenkins.log seems to contain a stack trace, but you did not show us enough lines to understand whether the stack trace is related to your test.

Comment: I had the same issue few months ago, but it was because of lack of memory available.
Try clearing all cache memory, temp data, try restart of Jenkins server with cache cleaning or increase the RAM of the Jenkins machine (also disk size if it is low). I hope this will help you.

Comment: Have you find out the issue... i am also facing the same issue

Comment: @Prasad Nope. I couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsTHK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsTHK.png)@Arun Ramachandran im also facing this issue. i turned on --debugfile in my command hoping it would give me some information. i have attached an image showing the debug info. it seems to be stuck in "Maximize Browser Window" keyword. i tried updating the chromedriver and restarting the Jenkins service but im still getting the issue. When i run the test in the server itself, it is passing without issues. have you tried Mayur's suggestion? i want to try it but i dont know how to do it or if

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/q/25186413/6793637

Comment: You should force robot framework to exit with exit code 0 ,

Comment: When we had issues like this, i think it was caused by the browser trying to access something that was firewalled.